# npm karma phantomJS undefined is not a constructor

Tags: reactjs, npm, phantomjs, karma-runner, redux

When running tests for a react-redux application with Karma, they were all passing with webkit but failing with phantomJS with the following error:

`TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'Object.assign({} [...]`

This would also crash the test runner.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Installing and configuring phantomjs-polyfill-object-assign fixed the issue.

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs-polyfill-object-assign